# Pattern in a matrix with dot and hash

Tags: java, algorithm

Find patterns in a given matrix.

I have a matrix with values '.' and '#'

Now I want to find count with the given pattern in the matrix :

```
a) 
##

b)
#
#
```

For the above pattern, the cells if exist surrounding them should be '.'

I am able to create successful logic for it:

```
static int getMatches(String[] B, int m, int n) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean[][] flag = new boolean[m][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        String S = B[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            char c = S.charAt(j);
            boolean valid = true;
            if (c == '#' && flag[i][j] == false) {
                if (j + 1 < n && S.charAt(j + 1) == '#' && flag[i][j + 1] == false) {
                    int[][] adj = { { 0, -1 }, { 0, 2 }, { -1, 0 }, { -1, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };
                    valid = isValid(adj, i, j, m, n, B);
                } else {
                    valid = false;
                }
            } else {
                valid = false;
            }

            if (c == '#' && !valid && flag[i][j] == false) {
                if (i + 1 < m && S.charAt(i + 1) == '#' && flag[i + 1][i] == false) {
                    int[][] adj = { { 0, -1 }, { 1, -1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 0, 1 }, { -1, 0 }, { 2, 0 } };
                    valid = isValid(adj, i, j, m, n, B);
                } else {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
            flag[i][j] = true;
            if (valid) {
                count++;
            }
        }

    }
    return count;
}

static boolean isValid(int[][] adj, int i, int j, int m, int n, String[] B) {
    for (int a = 0; a < adj.length; a++) {
        int i1 = i + adj[a][0];
        int j1 = j + adj[a][1];
        if (i1 >= 0 && i1 < m) {
            if (j1 >= 0 && j1 < n) {
                char d = B[i1].charAt(j1);
                if (d == '#') {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now I want to change the pattern to 3 cells like this:

```
a) 
###

b)
#
#
#

c)
##
#

d)
##
 #
 
e) 
#
##

f)
 #
##
```

How to build logic for this? Is their a way to extend my above code or is there a better approach to solve this problem.

Comment: I would recursively count the adjacent '#' fields, and if the count is equal to a certain number, than it is a match. This ensures that they are surrounded by '.' characters, and any pattern is identified. If you need a code, I can provide one, if you're not familiar with recursions.

Comment: @ArtúrManóMarschal, yes please provide

Answer (score 0):

Shared solution should work with any matrix of any symbols and number of rows/columns

Let's assume next parameters that we'll have as our input:

1. Matrix is represented as two-dimensional array - matrix[r][c], where r - number of rows in matrix, c - number of columns in matrix
2. Matrix has all its cells filled with some symbols
3. Pattern is represented as two-dimensional array - arr[k][m], where k - number of rows in pattern, m - number of columns in pattern
4. Algorithm will iterate each column of each row in matrix
5. Pattern can potentially be present in cell[x][y] only if next conditions are met:

   - x + k <= r (there are enough of matrix rows below this one (including current row) to include number of pattern rows)
   - y + m <= c (there are enough of matrix columns right of this one (including current column) to include number of pattern columns)
6. Comparison of pattern to current matrix cells says that they are equal. Comparison in done based on next conditions:

   - if pattern character is null - continue comparison
   - if pattern character is equal to matrix character - continue comparison
   - if pattern character is not equal to matrix character - end comparison, pattern is not located in this cell
   - if all pattern symbols checked - pattern is found in given matrix cell
7. Result of comparison in represented in 0-based index pairs

Let's get to the code.
We will have next classes:

1. Pattern Rule - represents pattern to be found. please specify nulls manually to make actually 2-dimensional array of equal row/col count

   ```
   private static final class PatternRule {

       private final Character[][] pattern;
       private final int rowCount;
       private final int colCount;

       private PatternRule(Character[][] pattern) {
           this.pattern = pattern;
           this.rowCount = pattern.length;
           this.colCount = pattern[0].length;
       }

       public int getRowCount() {
           return rowCount;
       }

       public int getColCount() {
           return colCount;
       }

       public Character getCharacterAt(int row, int column) {
           return pattern[row][column];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Found Pattern Location - class to represent found cells for pattern locations

   ```
   private static final class FoundPatternLocation {
       private final int rowIndex;
       private final int colIndex;

       private FoundPatternLocation(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
           this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
           this.colIndex = colIndex;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "["  + rowIndex + "][" + colIndex + "]";
       }
   }
   ```
3. Matrix - class that creates matrix and performs search of pattern locations

   ```
   private static final class Matrix {
       private final Character[][] matrix;
       private final int rowCount;
       private final int colCount;

       private Matrix(int rowCount, int colCount, Character[][] matrix) {
           this.rowCount = rowCount;
           this.colCount = colCount;
           this.matrix = matrix;
       }

       public static Matrix createMatrix(int rowCount, int colCount, char[] matrixSymbols) {
           Character[][] newMatrix = new Character[colCount][rowCount];

           Random rand = new Random();

           for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
               for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++) {
                   // select random char from allowed symbols
                   newMatrix[rowIndex][colIndex] = matrixSymbols[rand.nextInt(matrixSymbols.length)];
               }
           }

           return new Matrix(rowCount, colCount, newMatrix);
       }

       public void printMatrix() {
           System.out.println("---- Matrix -----");
           for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
               List<String> rowValues = new ArrayList<>();

               for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++) {
                   rowValues.add(String.valueOf(matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]));
               }

               String printableRowString = String.join(" ", rowValues);
               System.out.println(printableRowString);
           }
           System.out.println("-----------------");
       }

       public List<FoundPatternLocation> findPatternLocations(PatternRule patternRule) {
           List<FoundPatternLocation> actualPatternLocation = new ArrayList<>();

           for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < this.rowCount; rowNum++) {
               for (int colNum = 0; colNum < this.colCount; colNum++) {
                   if (isPatternFittingToCurrentCell(rowNum, colNum, patternRule)) { // can pattern be located in this cell?
                       if (isPatternLocatedInCell(rowNum, colNum, patternRule)) { // is pattern actually located in this cell?
                           actualPatternLocation.add(new FoundPatternLocation(rowNum, colNum));
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           return actualPatternLocation;
       }

       private boolean isPatternFittingToCurrentCell(int matrixRowIndex, int matrixColIndex, PatternRule patternRule) {
           int patternRowsCount = patternRule.getRowCount();
           int patternColumnsCount = patternRule.getColCount();

           int availableMatrixRowsForPattern = rowCount - matrixRowIndex;
           int availableMatrixColsForPattern = colCount - matrixColIndex;

           return patternRowsCount <= availableMatrixRowsForPattern && patternColumnsCount <= availableMatrixColsForPattern;
       }

       private boolean isPatternLocatedInCell(int rowNum, int colNum, PatternRule patternRule) {
           int patternRowsCount = patternRule.getRowCount();
           int patternColumnsCount = patternRule.getColCount();

           for (int currentPatternRowIndex = 0; currentPatternRowIndex < patternRowsCount; currentPatternRowIndex++) {
               for (int currentPatternColIndex = 0; currentPatternColIndex < patternColumnsCount; currentPatternColIndex++) {
                   int currentMatrixRowIndex = currentPatternRowIndex + rowNum;
                   int currentMatrixColIndex = currentPatternColIndex + colNum;
                   Character currentMatrixCharacter = matrix[currentMatrixRowIndex][currentMatrixColIndex];
                   Character currentPatternCharacter = patternRule.getCharacterAt(currentPatternRowIndex, currentPatternColIndex);

                   if (currentPatternCharacter == null) {
                       continue;
                   }

                   if (Objects.equals(currentMatrixCharacter, currentPatternCharacter)) {
                       continue;
                   }

                   return false;

               }
           }

           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Class to perform execution

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int rowCount = 5;
       int colCount = 5;
       char[] matrixSymbols = new char[] {'✓', 'X'};

       Matrix matrix = Matrix.createMatrix(rowCount, colCount, matrixSymbols);
       matrix.printMatrix();

       PatternRule patternRuleA = createPatternRuleA();
       PatternRule patternRuleB = createPatternRuleB();
       PatternRule patternRuleC = createPatternRuleC();

       List<FoundPatternLocation> patternLocationsA = matrix.findPatternLocations(patternRuleA);
       printPatternLocations(patternLocationsA, "Pattern A");
       List<FoundPatternLocation> patternLocationsB = matrix.findPatternLocations(patternRuleB);
       printPatternLocations(patternLocationsB, "Pattern B");
       List<FoundPatternLocation> patternLocationsC = matrix.findPatternLocations(patternRuleC);
       printPatternLocations(patternLocationsC, "Pattern C");
   }

   private static void printPatternLocations(List<FoundPatternLocation> patternLocations, String patternName) {
       System.out.println("---- " + patternName + " ----");
       String string = patternLocations.stream().map(FoundPatternLocation::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("; "));
       System.out.println(string);
       System.out.println("--------");
   }

   private static PatternRule createPatternRuleA() {
       Character[][] chars = {
               {'✓', '✓', '✓'}
       };

       return new PatternRule(chars);
   }

   private static PatternRule createPatternRuleB() {
       Character[][] chars = {
               {'✓'},
               {'✓'},
               {'✓'}
       };

       return new PatternRule(chars);
   }

   private static PatternRule createPatternRuleC() {
       Character[][] chars = {
               {'✓', '✓'},
               {'✓', null}
       };

       return new PatternRule(chars);
   }
   ```

Example of execution:

```
---- Matrix -----
✓ ✓ X ✓ X
✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
X X X X ✓
X ✓ X X ✓
X X ✓ ✓ ✓
-----------------
---- Pattern A ----
[1][0]; [1][1]; [1][2]; [4][2]
--------
---- Pattern B ----
[1][4]; [2][4]
--------
---- Pattern C ----
[0][0]
--------
```

Comment: I tried executing this code in my eclipse but got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` at line `List<FoundPatternLocation> patternLocationsC = matrix.findPatternLocations(patternRuleC);`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the problem can be simplified to finding the adjacent `#` fields, and their area must match a certain number.

So I have created the following code:

```
public static int getMatches(String[] matrix, int m, int n, int patternArea) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        String row = matrix[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            char item = row.charAt(j);
            if (item == '#' && countArea(matrix, i, j) + 1 == patternArea) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static int countArea( String[] matrix, final int i, final int j ) {
    int area = 0;
    setVisited(matrix, i,j);
    if (matrix[Math.max(i-1, 0)].charAt(j) == '#') {
        area += countArea(matrix, i-1, j) + 1;
    }
    if (matrix[Math.min(i+1, matrix.length-1)].charAt(j) == '#') {
        area += countArea(matrix, i+1, j) + 1;
    }
    if (matrix[i].charAt(Math.max(j-1, 0)) == '#') {
        area += countArea(matrix, i, j-1) + 1;
    }
    if (matrix[i].charAt(Math.min(j+1, matrix[0].length()-1)) == '#') {
        area += countArea(matrix, i, j+1) + 1;
    }
    return area;
}

private static void setVisited( final String[] matrix, final int i, final int j ) {
    char[] rowChars = matrix[i].toCharArray();
    rowChars[j] = '0';
    matrix[i] = String.valueOf(rowChars);
}
```

Explanation:

1. Find at least 1 `#` field
2. From that position, recursively find any adjacent `#` fields - `countArea` method
3. Always mark already visited fields - I chose `0`, but any other char will do other than `.` and `#`
4. Finally, if the area is matching a given number (`patternArea`), increase count variable

This is working only, if you include all of the patterns for a certain number. Given your example, you did just that. In case you really want to do exact pattern matching, then this approach will not be useful for your case.